# Ionic 2 Events Not Passing Data To Different Page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, dom-events

I'm using Ionic 2 or 3 events in order to pass data from my login page to one of my Providers that's shared between my pages. After the user logs in, I want to send the token to my provider file and lock up all the routes. Essentially I want to write code such as:

`if (token) {allow access to routes} else {no access}`

```
  doLogin() {
    // this.navCtrl.setRoot('MenuPage')
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'login', JSON.stringify(this.user), {headers:headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.events.publish('token:added', data.token)

        if(data.login === 'yes') {
          this.token = data.token;
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('MenuPage')
        }
        else {
          alert('Bad login cridentials');
        }
      })
  }
```

Provider

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log("are we here?")
    this.events.subscribe('token:added', (data) => {
      console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> token added is ', data)
    })
  }
```

The interesting thing is, my provider is technically not ever loaded to the screen, so I'm not sure if I should be using ionViewDidLoad. But, just to test if ionViewDidLoad is the problem, I imported the function above in my menu page, but I am still not accessing the token: added data. I can see my "are we here?" string logged, but that's it.

I am getting the token back, users are logging in. I just want to authenticate the users using token that my server is sending to the front end.

Are there any other way to pass data from my login function to my providers w/o using the push method since my provider isn't going to be landed to the screen?

Comment: can you update your question with your complete provider file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
doLogin() {
 // this.navCtrl.setRoot('MenuPage')
 var self = this;
 let headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

 this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'login', JSON.stringify(this.user), {headers:headers})
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    self.events.publish('token:added', data.token)

    if(data.login === 'yes') {
      self.token = data.token;
      self.navCtrl.setRoot('MenuPage')
    }
    else {
      alert('Bad login cridentials');
    }
  })
```

}

In `subscribe`, your scope has changed so you cannot use `this` to reference to the outside scope. One way is to store your scope into a variable and use that variable as the global scope.

You can also try printing the scopes inside `subscribe` to get a better understanding.

```
console.log(self);
console.log(this);
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: hey, thanks for replying. That didn't work. I understand the self vs this issue has to do with function binding, right? If so, doesn't the arrow function takes care of that possible issue? It automatically binds the this key word to the function it was invoked in.

Comment: ahhh oversight on my part! What about `console.log(this.events)`? So the events doesnt get published but does the navCtrl sucessfully go to the MenuPage?

Comment: hmm, maybe try having a function that purely publishes the event and see if that works? Dont bother about the `http.post` first. Then from there maybe you can know where the bug lies at.

Comment: i can do that, but my bigger issue is how to pass this to my providers. any idea?

Comment: I am doing like you also. Using `events` and its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Provider will not have ionViewDidLoad event. So the subscription to the event should be done in ngOnInit() callback function in provider class, rest of the code looks good. Also make sure that provider is initialized before login event is publishing. In your Menupage the event data is not logged because you are publishing the event before the MenuPage is being loaded. That's why the log added inside the event subscription is not executed.